# PHP Insertion issue with 'id'

Tags: mysql, ajax, php-7

I'm trying to resolve an issue with an app. Originally we had problems due to PHP upgrading from PHP5 to PHP7. This seems to have been corrected in places, but now I am having problems again.

Can someone please check the syntax to check if it is inputting right?

```
if($_POST['create_special_appointment']){ 
    $customer_id   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['customer'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $category_id   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['category'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $start_date    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['start_date'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $end_date      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['end_date'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $start_time = htmlspecialchars($_POST['start_time'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $end_time   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['end_time'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $booked_for =  post_array_to_explode($_POST['booked_for']);
    $notes      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['notes'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $session_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['session_id'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $time       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $agent_id   = get_agent_from_session($session_id, 'id');

    //if(!($start_time)){$start_time = '00:00';}
    //if(!($end_time)){$end_time = '00:00';}
    //$start_date = $start_date.' '.$start_time;
    //$end_date = $end_date.' '.$end_time;

    $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
    $start_date = $start_date.' '.$start_time.":00";
    $end_date = $end_date.' '.$end_time.":00";

    //$start_date = format_datetime_mysql($start_date);
    //$end_date = format_datetime_mysql($end_date);

    $insert = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO calendar_special(start_date, end_date, notes, category_special_id, added_by, booked_for, date_added, customer_id) VALUES ('$start_date', '$end_date', '$notes', '$category_id', '$agent_id', '$booked_for', '$time', '$customer_id')");
    if($insert){
        $notification_msg[] = array(type=>'alert-success', h4=>'Success!', msg=>'Appointment Created');
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }else{
        $notification_msg[] = array(type=>'alert-warning', h4=>'Warning!', msg=>'Appointment NOT Created');
        mysqli_error($con);
        var_dump($_REQUEST);
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    }
    //temp-code
    //var_dump($insert);
}
```

Actual form code is:

```
<select name="customer" id="customer-single" style="width:100%"> 
        <option value="">Select a customer (Optional)</option>
        <?php  foreach(customer_array($ajax['0']) as $customer){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $customer['id'] ?>">
        <?php echo $customer['business_name'] ?> - <?php echo $customer['first_name'] ?> <?php echo $customer['last_name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And the error I'm getting is:

---

> "Warning! Appointment NOT Created"
>
> array(11) { ["session_id"]=> string(64)
>   "c5ec66786328e97af8f8fb6771912b58c5869986816b3d2bc9916b7e740cff44"
>   ["create_special_appointment"]=> string(4) "true" ["customer"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["category"]=> string(1) "1" ["start_date"]=> string(10)
>   "2018-10-23" ["start_time"]=> string(5) "10:35" ["end_date"]=>
>   string(10) "2018-10-31" ["end_time"]=> string(5) "10:35"
>   ["booked_by"]=> string(1) "5" ["booked_for"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(2) "71" } ["notes"]=> string(18) " Paul Holiday Test" } Array (
>   [0] => 22007 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: '' for column
>   'customer_id' at row 1 )

---

Apologies if this question has been worded incorrectly, and if so, please advise.

Comment: As you can see in the dump of your request, php receives just an empty string from your customer select. Is this field rendered correctly? Can select from different customers?

Comment: That's because your column accepts an int and you are sending a string.

try converting your first line to `$customer_id   = (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST['customer'], ENT_QUOTES);`